# Python mock, patch os.environ returns None

Tags: python

I have a simple module:

```
# my_module
from os.path import join
from os import environ

some_file_name = 'foo.txt'

def file_path():
    join(environ['TARGET_DIRECTORY'], some_file_name)
```

And a simple test:

```
import os
import unittest
from os.path import join

from mock import patch
from my_module import some_file_name, file_path


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_can_create_path(self):
        some_folder = '/path/to/directory'
        with patch.dict('my_module.environ', {'TARGET_DIRECTORY': some_folder}):
            self.assertEqual(file_path(), join(some_folder, some_file_name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I expected that the call to `environ['TARGET_DIRECTORY']` would return `'/path/to/directory'` but it returns `None`

Comment: Is `my_module` inside some package?

Comment: @J0HN, as mentioned below, I have just switched back to Python from Scala where return keywords are not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *function* returns `None`, as there is no explicit `return` statement. Add a `return`:

```
def file_path():
    return join(environ['TARGET_DIRECTORY'], some_file_name)
```

The mock patch worked fine otherwise.

Comment: Doh! Of course. I have just switched back to Python after months of Scala, where the return statement isn't needed.